# Recover Win Pro product key after installed Win Home

Tags: windows-10, product-key, recovery

My case is a bit special.

Normally when I re-install Windows as the same as the previous it would automatically activate Windows for me.

But this time, I have Windows 10 Pro (OEM), have to install recovery (from the laptop brand) => back to Windows 10 Home (ridiculous); then I want to restore my "Pro" version. How to I do that? Can I extract my "Pro" product key then use it again?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Can I extract my "Pro" product key then use it again?" - It's unnecessary.  When you install Windows 10, from a installation media, your Windows 10 Professional key will automatically be detected and the installation will be properly activated.

Comment: Yes sir I knew that `Normally when I re-install Windows as the same as the previous it would automatically activate Windows for me`. I'm just curious whether I lost the `Pro` version after installed `Home` version or not. Btw thank you very much! The accepted answer contain fully information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Windows 10 Pro is OEM, meaning that it came with the computer,
then you should have no problems restoring it after installing another
Windows version.

Windows 10 Pro should re-activate itself automatically, either by the
hardware fingerprint (digital entitlement) or (sometimes) by the
serial number that is burnt into the BIOS.

If you're worried, you could take an image backup of the entire disk,
then restore that image. Windows will be restored as activated and
in exactly the same state as before.
A good software for that is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).